# What's host property function

Tags: angular

Can anyone tell me what's host property? How does it work? I can find these codes during studying anyone's codes in github. The man tried to use password input component into login page component. I've understood so far but 'host' property confused me.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-password-input',
  templateUrl: './password-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./password-input.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => PasswordInputComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  host: {
    '(change)': 'onChange($event.target.value)',
    '(input)': 'onChange($event.target.value)',
    '(blur)': 'onTouched()',
  },
})
```

These are included in the rest of the code:

```
onChange: any = () => { };

disabled = false;


  writeValue(value: string): void {
    this.value = value;
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

host metadata is an alternative way to declare [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener)/[HostBinding](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding) decorators.

See [this guideline](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#hostlistenerhostbinding-decorators-versus-host-metadata) for a comparison.